# how to manage user login and admin login django?

Tags: python, django

I have an issue with managing login with normal user and admin user. The issue is I don't know how to distinguish an admin user from a normal user. Please look at the image to understand.

[image: look image]

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking... are you just trying to work out if a user is an admin or not?..

Comment: Yes!!i don't know how to check user is a admin or normal user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Django user.is_superuser attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser)

Simply in your view:

```
if request.user.is_superuser:
    '''Do the magic'''
```

To make the user an admin, you set this attribute to True - this is normally done within Django admin app.

Comment: is_superuser i create admin user with this?

Comment: You check if the user issuing the request is admin.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you decide on what is an admin account or not

You either need to use `is_staff` or `is_superuser`

- is_staff:  Designates whether this user can access the admin site.
- is_superuser:  Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.

From this, the best way to actually implement it is with a decorator

```
def is_admin(user):
     return user.is_staff
@user_passes_test(is_admin)
def my_view(request):
```